# Why are error messages (usually) all lowercase?

Tags: lua

In Lua, there are many ways to generate error messages:

```
[soniex2@soniex-pc ~]$ lua
Lua 5.3.1  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> hi!
stdin:1: syntax error near '!'
> ::
>> ::
stdin:2: <name> expected near '::'
> ~
stdin:1: unexpected symbol near '~'
> pcall()
stdin:1: bad argument #1 to 'pcall' (value expected)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'pcall'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
> table.insert()
stdin:1: bad argument #1 to 'insert' (table expected, got no value)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'table.insert'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

And as you can see, all the error messages are in all-lowercase.

Why is this?

(This isn't exclusive to Lua, but there wasn't/isn't a tag for it.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about language design decisions and not a programming problem.

Comment: What would you expect?

Comment: Proper case, like in this comment.

Comment: @EdCottrell Uhh... There have been questions like this before.

Comment: @SoniEx2 Yes, and they are usually closed quickly. The fact that other people have asked similar, off-topic questions does not mean this one is on-topic.

Comment: @EdCottrell And sometimes they're answered nicely.

Comment: @SoniEx2 Well, the answer is pretty obvious: because the Lua creators felt like doing it that way. But whatever the reason they felt that way, this question is still off-topic.

Comment: =/ -1 could damage your reputation.  If you already know that it was off-topic, you should look around other sites and don't play with your reputation. =/

Comment: @EdCottrell It isn't exclusive to Lua. Most programming languages use all-lowercase for their errors.

Comment: @AMaduro There is no "language design" Q/A site. Programming and language design go hand-in-hand so this was the next best thing, so I thought it wasn't completely off-topic.

Comment: @SoniEx2 I'm just saying that if you saw that it was off-topic, and you are seeing that these people are saying that it's off-topic, then no matter if it is not off-topic, you could get -1. I been in that situation, too. Where I have a question and I look around, and users closed similar questions, and so I delete my question as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Lowercase syndrome" is programmer's inclination to use only lowercase letters to avoid accidentally creating another object (file, variable) by using the same name with another letter case.

For example, Linux is a subject to this syndrome (many system folder names are ugly).

Lua is subject to this syndrome too: it's ordinary to use ugly identifiers `getmetatable`, `rawset`, `tostring`, `require("md5")` instead of their proper forms: `GetMetatable`, `RawSet`, `ToString`, `require("MD5")`.

And even error messages are affected by lowercase syndrome.